# Как оптимизировать код с++

Tags: c++, функции, оптимизация, инспекция-кода, численные-методы

Помогите, пожалуйста, оптимизировать код, преподаватель заставил, а я совсем не понимаю, что еще можно поменять.
Само задание:
Вычислить определенный интеграл∫f(x)dx используя формулы: средних прямоугольников, трапеций и Симпсона, разделив отрезок интегрирования на n равных частей. Оценить погрешность вычислений.

f(x) = (x + 1.9) * sin(x) * (x / 3) a = 1, b = 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
 
double f(double x)
{
return (x + 1.9) * sin(x) * (x / 3);
}
 
double Rectangular(double a, double b, int n)
{
double h = (b - a) / n;
double sum = (f(a) + f(b)) / 2;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
sum += f(a + h * (i + 0.5));
}
sum = sum * h;
return sum;
}
 
double Trapeze(double a, double b, int n)
{
double h = (b - a) / n;
double sum = f(a) + f(b);
for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++)
{
sum += 2 + f(a + i * h);
}
sum *= h / 2;
return sum;
}
 
double Simpson(double a, double b, int n)
{
double h = (b - a) / n;
double sum = f(a) + f(b);
int k;
for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++)
{
k = 2 + 2 * (i % 2);
sum += k + f(a + i * h);
}
sum *= h / 3;
return sum;
}
 
int main()
{
double a = 1, b = 2;
int n = 0;
cout << "Количество отрезков: ";
cin >> n;
double h = (b - a) / n;
 
cout << "Метод средних прямоугольников: " << Rectangular(a, b, n) << " ПОГРЕШНОСТЬ: " << 1.018 * h * h * (b - a) / 24 << endl;
cout << "Метод трапеций: " << Trapeze(a, b, n) << " ПОГРЕШНОСТЬ: " << 1.018 * h * h * (b - a) / 12 << endl;
cout << "Метод Симпсона: " << Simpson(a, b, n) << " ПОГРЕШНОСТЬ: " << (4.38 * pow(h, 5)) / 90 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Именно *оптимизировать*? Не *исправить*?

Comment: @Harry если есть что можно исправить, то прошу указать на это

Comment: А может отформатировать? Оптимизации там можно делать, но думаю, они выйдут за пределы Вашего курса

Comment: Вас (и преподавателя) не удивляет, что все три метода дают разные результаты? Отличающиеся далеко за пределами погрешности? У вас же сами функции интерирования неверно написаны.

Answer (score 1):

OK, я бы делал так — исправляя и оптимизируя:

```
double Rectangular(double (*f)(double), double a, double b, int n)
{
    double h = (b - a) / n;
    double sum = 0;
    for(a += h/2; a < b; a += h) sum += f(a);
    return sum *h;
}

double Trapeze(double (*f)(double), double a, double b, int n)
{
    double h = (b - a) / n;
    double sum = (f(a) + f(b))/2;
    while(a < b-3*h/2) sum += f(a+=h);
    return sum*h;
}

double Simpson(double (*f)(double), double a, double b, int n)
{
    double h = (b - a) / n;
    double sum = -(f(a)+f(b));
    int    coeff = 4;
    for(; a < b+h/2; a += h) sum += (coeff = 6 - coeff) * f(a);
    return sum * h / 3;
}
```

В смысле погрешностей — это ваши с преподом заморочки :) — как именно оценивать погрешность, сюда я не лез.